# Get the start and end date based on working dates in the week in asp.net c#

Tags: .net

i want startdate enddate.based on taskid
in the database datatable data contain like
table:

```
TaskId Mondate tuedate weddate...sundate monhours tuehours wedhours thuhours.... sunhours
Tsk100 3/6/13  4/6/13  5/6/13..  9/6/13   Null      2         2          1            2
```

so this time i want like startdate=4/6/13  and enddate=9/6/13. 
so please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CASE`. Replace `....` with the rest of the day-hours-columns and their related dates.

```
SELECT StartDate = CASE 
                     WHEN monhours IS NOT NULL THEN mondate 
                     ELSE 
                       CASE 
                         WHEN tuehours IS NOT NULL THEN tuedate 
                         .... 
                         ELSE 
                           CASE 
                             WHEN sunhours IS NOT NULL THEN sundate 
                           END 
                       END 
                   END, 
       EndDate = CASE 
                   WHEN sunhours IS NOT NULL THEN sundate 
                   .... 
                   ELSE 
                     CASE 
                       WHEN monhours IS NOT NULL THEN mondate 
                     END 
                 END 
FROM   dbo.tablename
```